# "print" not working when redirecting to another application

Tags: python, windows, redirect, printing, stdout

I ran across this strange problem when redirecting the output of a python application. I was running bitmessage [from source](https://github.com/Bitmessage/PyBitmessage) which prints quite a big amount of stuff to the console.

I tried filtering out some of the lines with an application I have written. When I redirect the output to a file `python.exe src\bitmessagemain.py>file.txt` it works fine, everything is sent to the text file. When I pipe the output into another application `python.exe src\bitmessagemain.py | someapp.exe` all "print" statements seem to be ignored. They are not redirected and not piped to the other application.

The redirection does not even works when using system internal commands like "more" and "type CON"

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: I wonder if Windows supports Unix style pipes. Does it?

Comment: @LutzHorn It should: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Does `python -c "print('test')" | more` work?

Comment: Since `more.com` is external, there's probably nothing wrong on the Python side. someapp.exe could be reading from the console directly, or changing its behavior if it detects that stdin isn't console input.

Comment: @eryksun more.com uses stdin to read. The internal "type" command also does not works. it's only the print statements that do not work, there are some "logger.debug" statements, which will print.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I found the answer by experimenting. Seems that supplying the command line switch `-u` solves the problem by setting the output into unbuffered binary mode. Docs: [cmd option -u](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)

I don't know about any side effects, but it seems to completely work.

The output buffer is vastly larger than the size of the visible console area for some reason. I printed text in an endless loop and as I printed about half a GB(!) the output got flushed. This only gets done when using redirection. Might be an attempt to optimize performance.

Comment: Python's `print` statement/function doesn't flush the file buffer after each write, that's why unbuffered mode fixes the problem.

Comment: Normally the buffer is desired to optimize writing data with fewer system calls, and the reading process on the other side of the pipe detects that stdin isn't interactive to adapt to processing buffered I/O. You have yet to describe the complete problem to make it clear what you're trying to do and why the other end of the pipe has a problem with the default buffering.

Comment: A better way that using unbuffered IO is to do `sys.stdout.flush()` when appropriate